# Easiest way to set up a linux-hosted file server for wife's windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-server

I would like to use an extra physical hard drive in my linux server to provide my wife a place to backup her Windows XP desktop. I am willing to format this drive as NTFS (or anything else) and have it dedicated to this purpose. I am wondering what is the easiest way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up [Samba](http://www.samba.org/).  Then you can either have her manually drag and drop stuff she wants backed up over to there or you can set up some automatic process on her machine to do so every so often.